# Universal Print via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, printers, outsystems

I have integrated universal printer in my App(outsystems) using [Microsoft graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/universal-print-concept-overview#extending-universal-print-to-support-pull-printing), it's working as expected except `pageRanges`, for example I have document containing 5 pages and I want to print 3rd and 4th page only but it is printing all 5 pages every time.

Following is the JSON representation of the request

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "quality": "medium",
    "dpi": 600,
    "duplexMode": "oneSided",
    "copies": 1,
    "colorMode": "auto",
    "mediaSize": "A4",
    "collate": true,
    "feedOrientation": "longEdgeFirst",
    "fitPdfToPage": false,
    "inputBin": "tray-1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "pageRanges": [
      {
        "start": 3,
        "end": 4
      }
    ], 
    "pagesPerSheet": 1,
    "scaling": "none"
  }
}
```